# Implementing \bibhang in multibib

Tags: indentation, natbib, moderncv, subdividing, multibib

I have been using `moderncv` as a template for several years, but I am now trying to solve a problem that has long bothered me: being able to use `\bibhang` in my list of publications. The `moderncv` template seems to favor using `multibib`, which is great, but as far as I can tell `multibib` does not support anything related to `\bibhang`. As is often done, I strongly prefer indenting subsequent lines of citations within the bibliography.

I was trying to use `natbib`, but it doesn't allow for multiple bibliographies and I would like to separate my journal publications from my poster presentations, etc.

Does anyone know how to indent subsequent lines while using `multibib`?

Here is example code:

```
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-0pt}} % 0 does not modify vspace

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey'
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     % if you want to change the width    of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width o
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths


% personal data
\firstname{\textsc{Me}}
\familyname{\textsc{Myself}}
\title{Really Awesome}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{500 Way}{UT 84108}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{801.555.5555}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{801.222.2222}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\fax{Upon Request}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{email@email.com}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\setlength{\bibhang}{3em}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{journal,oral,poster,submitted,indraft}{{Journal Publications},{Oral Presentations},   {Poster Presentations},{Sub

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2012 -- Present}{Student}{University}{UT}{}
    {\textit{GPA: NA}}
\section{Skills and Qualifications}
\subsection{Programming Languages:}
\cvitem{}{  \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{1em} \vspace{-12pt}
        \resitem{Java/JNI}
    \end{itemize}
    }   
\section{Publications}
% Specify the bibtex style that you want for each paper type
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliographystylejournal{unsrt}
\bibliographystyleposter{unsrt}
\bibliographystyleoral{unsrt}

\nocitejournal{myarticle:2012fk}
\bibliographyjournal{my_publications}

\vspace{25pt}
\nociteoral{mypresentation:2011fk}
\bibliographyoral{my_publications}

\vspace{25pt}
\nociteposter{myposter:2011uz}
\bibliographyposter{my_publications}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `multibib` isn't compatible with `natbib`? The user guide for multibib, at least, doesn't seem to hold this view. To wit: "The multibib package is compatible with cite, inlinebib, jurabib (to be loaded before multibib), natbib, suthesis and [the] KOMA-Script classes." Have you tried loading `natbib` to set the `\bibhang` length parameter and using multibib's `\newcites` mechanism?

Comment: @mico Thank you for the suggestion. I tried loading `natbib` and defining `bibhang` but it does not seem to work. I've added a minimal example. Any ideas? Thanks! NOTE: if I load natbib before multibib, it doesn't have any effect. If I load it after multibib, it hangs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading `natbib` plus `multibib` seems to mangle `moderncv`s `thebibliography` environment, namely, to ignore the lengths `\hintscolumnwidth` and `\separatorcolumnwidth`. I suggest to do without `natbib`. Instead, I define the new length `\bibhang` and use this length to modify `thebibliography`.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{classic}

\firstname{Me}
\familyname{Myself}

\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
}{%
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
  \advance\leftmargin\bibhang
  \itemindent-\bibhang
}{}{}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{journal,oral}{{Journal Publications},{Oral Presentations}}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
    A subtitle that is long enough to cause a line break in the bibliography}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{journal.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha: \sometext},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{oral.bib}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo: \sometext},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Publications}

\nocitejournal{A01}
\bibliographystylejournal{unsrt}
\bibliographyjournal{\jobname}

\nociteoral{B02}
\bibliographystyleoral{unsrt}
\bibliographyoral{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! The sad thing is that I don't really understand what that modification is doing! I'll make that my homework. :) Thanks!